# Getting null values for current location when apply in mobile devices

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, null, location

I am getting null values for current location when I put my program in mobile device, it is working when I test it in emulators. I have also try other solution from this site but still doesn't work. I know that the problem is within lastKnownLocation and I think the way how I apply it was wrong. I also tested it outdoors and still not working. Can you check what's wrong with my program and explain why my program is not working in device.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_school_list, container, false);
    lvList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvSchools);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Log.d("","provider : "+provider);
    // String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);
    final Location currentLoc = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (currentLoc != null) {
        currentLoc.getLatitude();
        currentLoc.getLongitude();
        onLocationChanged(currentLoc);
    }

    if (Distance==true){
        double lat = currentLoc.getLatitude();
        double lng = currentLoc.getLongitude();
        ArrayList<Double> rangeList = getRangeList(lat, lng);
```

Here's my onLocationChange

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

}
```

I apply it in great circle distance formula so I want to get current latitude and longitude. 
I want to pass the values here but it always return null values
double lat = currentLoc.getLatitude();
double lng = currentLoc.getLongitude();

Comment: check is your device location service is on or not.

Comment: Yes sir , I always make sure it's on

Comment: you receive null values in onLocationChanges or you never receive the callback? in the second case, you have to go outdoor and wait a bit, GPS fix is not instant

Comment: I have tested it in other device and it perfectly works. Do you think there's nothing wrong with my code ? or is there a way I can improve this code in order to run my application in the device I receive error.